# What are examples of high-liquidity ERC777 tokens on ETHEREUM? Any other token standards apply too, as long as there's a beforeTransfer callback

Tags: solidity, tokens, security, solidity-0.8.x, erc-777

I'm looking to make a list of popular tokens that implement hooks on `transferFrom(address owner, address receiver, uint256 amount)` and are deployed on the **Ethereum** blockchain in particular.

For example, tokens that implement the ERC777 standard (https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc777)

I found a reference stating that, for instance, Bancor (BNT), MakerDAO (MKR), and Loopring (LRC) are all based on this standard.

(https://www.bitdegree.org/crypto/learn/crypto-terms/what-is-erc-777)

However, I believe that this information is outdated, and the current implementations of these tokens do not have any hooks.

Comment: This thread could be useful: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/2620